# Should I choose Indian, Asia Pacific or USA based server?

Tags: web-hosting

My website has 98% visitor from India and 2% from rest of the globe. Now, I am migrating to VPS.

Should, choose those hosts who have Data Center in India or nearer to India.

- Will it help to load pages quickly to my users (If Data center would be nearer to India. Assume, that i am subscribing VPS from standard hosts)?
- Will it help in SEO too (Google search engine).

Comment: Sorry but we already have a vast amount of questions and answers regarding selecting a web host, including regional information. Additionally, recommendations on services, software and resources is considered off-topic.

Comment: @SimonHayter: this question seems to be more about the impact the server location has when geotargeting.

Comment: Well as you have mentioned you have 98% of your traffic from INDIA. So, apart from lest turn around time (Ping) an Indian VPS will also help in ranking. So, its better to go for an INDIAN one if you can afford. They are a little costlier most of the time.. I think Digital Ocean had started providing INDIAN vps also..from the last month, you can try that also.. They are really good .

Comment: @atulquest93 I know this thats why I mentioned `including regional information`, many [questions on server location](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=server+location+is%3Aquestion) already. Currently there is not enough uniqueness about this question.

Comment: @SimonHayter, you are right I searched and found many questions as well. Now I just don't know why my answer below has been downvoted... Is it a common practice to downvote an answer if the question has been asked already?

Comment: It's common practice for users to up vote, or down vote, when engaging on the Stack Exchange network you should expect both... even the best answers receive some criticism. Also, please don't use the comment system to challenge the downvoting, nothing constrictive comes from it. PS. up vote from me :)

Comment: @atulquest93 Yeah,  Digital Ocean started their services in India (Bangalore).  The thing is that, Linode offering almost double resource than Digital Ocean. But Linode data center are located in Singapore and Tokyo. that's why I asked this question. If this distance doesn't matter then anyone would happily like to choose the server located outside of the India.

Comment: @Pavan Singapore / Indian server will serve almost equally there will be no  difference in speed /ping ... You may get some benefit over SEO if you use Indian server..

But, If your traffic is high better go with `Linode `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorter the distance between the 2 end-points (server - client), the faster is the communication, that's a fact; although using CDNs can help achieve faster distribution of the data/content across the globe.

As for SEO, server location would hardly make any difference if anything else is optimized and focused on your target location. **Although page load speeds can affect rankings- and page load speeds can be increased when you host far away from your users.

### [From G Webmasters FAQs](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-internationalisation#q9):

> **Q: Is the server location important for geotargeting?**
>   A: If you can
>   use one of the other means to set geotargeting (ccTLD or Search
>   Console’ geotargeting tool), you don’t need worry about the server’s
>   location. We do, however, recommend making sure that your website is
>   hosted in a way that will give your users fast access to it (which is
>   often done by choosing hosting near your users).

---

### Selecting hosting provider:

Apart of the server location, there are more important things to consider when choosing hosting provider. Some of the most important:

- Expertise
- Security
- Support and communication channels
- Technology and Infrastructure - And compatibility with your needs.
- General Terms of Services and Limitations
- Performance, Reliability and Uptime
- Scalability
- Add-on Services and Essential Features e.g. backups

Price is important as well, but shouldn't be the most important factor when you plan ahead for an important business project/website.

Generally, when something sounds as too good to be true, in most cases it isn't, so be aware and do extended research - ask for advices, recommendations, get in touch with the hosting providers for pre-sales questions etc.